# Problema al mostrar tabWidget con QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

Estoy trabajando con **PyQt**, con el tipo de ventana `QMainWindow`, al usar un `tabWidget` no me da error en absoluto pero cuando ejecuto el programa no me lo muestra. Sin embargo cuando cambio `QMainWindow` por `QWidget` y ejecuto, si lo muestra. Este es el script de prueba:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        label1 = QLabel("Example content contained in a tab.")
        label2 = QLabel("More example text in the second tab")
        textEdit = QTextEdit()

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(label1, "Tab 1")
        tabwidget.addTab(label2, "Tab 2")
        tabwidget.addTab(textEdit, "TextEdit")

        layout.addWidget(tabwidget, 0, 0)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = Window()
screen.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Con cambiar `class Window(QWidget)` por `class Window(QMainWindow)` ya no muestra el tabWidget en la app.

Como puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: basicamente: después del cambio por QMainWindow agregá self en el parámetro tabwidget = QTabWidget(), pero hay varias cosas que se podrían mejorar o cambiar, te recomendaria que uses setGeometry en lugar de grid, pero es subjetivo.

Answer (score 1):

[**Qt Main Window Framework**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()                                                       # !
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()                                           # +
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)                                # +         
        

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)                       # + self.centralwidget               
#        self.setLayout(layout)

        label1 = QLabel("Example content contained in a tab.")
        label2 = QLabel("More example text in the second tab")
        textEdit = QTextEdit()

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(label1, "Tab 1")
        tabwidget.addTab(label2, "Tab 2")
        tabwidget.addTab(textEdit, "TextEdit")

        layout.addWidget(tabwidget, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]